# compare integer to value in list in python

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to compare a value in list to a integer. can someone help how to do that

```
list = [1]
if list == number:
    print(number)
```

I want some thing like above, how to do

Comment: What is this comparison supposed to result in, and why?

Comment: You'll have to define number of course, but minimally its `if list[0] == number:` to compare the first value of a list to number.

Comment: `if number in list:`!?

Answer (score 0):

```
list = ["1","20","300","4000","50000"]
temp = int(list[x])
if temp == number:
    print(number)

#x = 1 to list# (number of values in list)
```

Be warned, if the string in the list isn't an integer (when removing "quotes"), it will throw an error

Answer (score 0):

if you have only one element in your list you can call him by index

```
list[0] == some_number:
```

if you have many elements you can sort through their by loop

```
for element in list:
    if element == some_number:
        print(some_number)
```